# Combining these two queries that deletes rows from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

My main table that I'm trying to delete rows from is the `customer` table.

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE Customer_ID = 1
```

Before I delete this table I am required to delete all the rows from my `appointments` table.

```
DELETE FROM appointments WHERE Customer_ID = 1
```

How would I perform combine these two queries that it first deletes all the rows from `appointments` first and then deletes the rows from `customer`?

Comment: You could use a `cascading delete` foreign key constraint and not have to worry about this.

Comment: i'm not allowed to change anything about the table

Comment: You can write stored procedure where first delete statement removes child table data then delete parent table data. ON DELETE cascade is better option here as you are not allowed to change anything.

Comment: would something like a simple transaction work? ```START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM appointments WHERE Customer_ID = 1;
DELETE FROM customers WHERE Customer_ID = 1;
COMMIT;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting parent child records from table by using stored procedure.

```
-- create parent table
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

insert into customers values (1), (2);

-- create child table
CREATE TABLE appointments (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
        REFERENCES customers (customer_id)
);

insert into appointments values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2);

-- create store procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE del_customer(p_customerId int)
BEGIN
        DELETE FROM appointments WHERE customer_id = p_customerId;
        
        DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_id = p_customerId;
        
END

-- call SP
CALL del_customer(1);
```

Check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef93a0df81a7b60c39ab26a4e2f383c4

Another way adding ON DELETE CASCADE at foreign key. When deleting master table data then corresponding child table data is automatically deleted.

```
-- create parent table
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

-- create child table
CREATE TABLE appointments (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
        REFERENCES customers (customer_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Please check the url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b0faea5408eabf871c2b1f3a0457a3f

Comment: Just curious why a stored procedure over a transaction, doesn't this also work? ```START TRANSACTION; DELETE FROM appointments WHERE Customer_ID = 1; DELETE FROM customers WHERE Customer_ID = 1; COMMIT;```

Comment: Just check the link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=76a189839a889051718155628abde602  where I've used your code. By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled. This means that, when not otherwise inside a transaction, each statement is atomic, as if it were surrounded by START TRANSACTION and COMMIT. You can use transaction inside stored procedure  if commit/rollback required.